# How to refresh JWT token using Docusign Java SDK?

Tags: java, jwt, docusignapi

How to refresh JWT token using Docusign Java SDK? Should I call:

`apiClient.configureJWTAuthorizationFlow()`

each time as it is done in samples (in JUnit Test)? But the method name sounds like it configures a flow. 
Is there any specific api to refresh the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JWT flow does not include a refresh token. So, to create a new Access Token, just re-do the JWT Flow.

The [Java example for JWT](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-java-jwt/) demonstrates a checkToken method which monitors the age of the token and creates a new one as needed.

We will be renaming the method in the near future. It will also only need the private key (as a string) then.

Comment: If `checkToken()` is getting invoked any time after token expiry time, this error throws. `received a non successful HTTP code 401 with response Body: '{ "errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid. Invalid access token"
}'`

Comment: Thank you @sura2k for the bug report. If you'd like to submit a pull request, that would be great. I've created internal DocuSign ticket DEVDOCS-641

Comment: Please ask a new question. Include the version of the DocuSign Java SDK that you're using. Thanks.